# StreamReader is not reading second line of text file after I have modified the text file

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I can not figure this out.
My project is to take a text file, read it into my program, change the values of it, then rewrite it back to that text file.
The program will work the first time, but then the second time I run it the for-next loop I use to read from the file says that there is no text on the second line. The code just stops after the first loop and brings up the application. Anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

Here is the StreamReader loop I use:

```
    Dim inventoryReader As New StreamReader("Inventory.txt")
    Dim line As String
    Dim inventorycounter As Decimal = 0
    Do Until inventoryReader.EndOfStream
        line = inventoryReader.ReadLine()
        inventoryinfo = line.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
        inventory(inventorycounter, 0) = inventoryinfo(0)
        inventory(inventorycounter, 1) = inventoryinfo(1)
        inventorycounter += 1
    Loop
    inventoryreader.close()
```

This is the StreamWriter loop I use:

```
    Dim output As New StreamWriter("Inventory.txt")
    For outputcounter As Integer = 0 To 16
        output.WriteLine(inventory(outputcounter, 0) & ControlChars.Tab & inventory(outputcounter, 1) & ControlChars.Cr)
    Next
    output.WriteLine(inventory(17, 0) & ControlChars.Tab & inventory(17, 1))
    output.Close()
```

I think the problem is that the program doesn't read the ControlChars.Cr the second time, but I have tried CrLf, Lf, and Nextline and nothing had worked.

Thanks for any and all help guys!

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct, your program writes Cr + Cr + Lf to the text file.  Confuzzling StreamReader, it will treat the first Cr is a line terminator.  So you'll read an empty line, kaboom when you index *inventoryinfo*

Remove *ControlChars.Cr* from the code.  StreamWriter.WriteLine() doesn't need any help, it already writes the proper line terminator.